# Excel replace function in access VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am trying to run some Excel VBA code inside access VBA . It almost work but I have problem with replace function.

```
Sub test2()
    Dim lngColumn As Long
    Dim xlx As Object, xlw As Object, xls As Object, xlc As Object
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim blnEXCEL As Boolean

    blnEXCEL = False

    ' Establish an EXCEL application object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xlx = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set xlx = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        blnEXCEL = True
    End If
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
    xlx.Visible = True
            
    ' Replace C:\Filename.xls with the actual path and filename
    ' of the EXCEL file from which you will read the data
    Set xlw = xlx.Workbooks.Open("Q:\21 Projekty\FlowControl\Flow.xlsx", , True) ' opens in read-only mode

    ' Replace WorksheetName with the actual name of the worksheet
    ' in the EXCEL file
    Set xls = xlw.Worksheets("Flow")
            
    ' Replace A1 with the cell reference from which the first data value
    ' (non-header information) is to be read
    Set xlc = xls.range("A1") ' this is the first cell that contains data
            
    With xls
        .Columns(2).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        SelectedColumn = SelectedColumn + 1
        
        .Columns(3).Copy _
            Destination:=.Columns(1)
            
        .Columns(2).Replace What:=" - *", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False 
    'Error there  Subscript out of range (Error 9) 
        
        .Columns(3).Replace What:="* - ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
        
        .Columns(2).AutoFit
        .Columns(3).AutoFit
    Errorhandling:
        'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        'End Sub
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Check such things as xlToRight, xlByRows, xlPart - Access won't understand them with late binding.  In Excel enter ?xlToRight into the Immediate window and it will return -4161.  Use the number it gives you.

Comment: If your code is working as is - it looks like you've set a reference to Excel, but are using late binding in the code - you define xlx as an Object rather than an Excel.Application.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was a real problem so my code in this part now looks like:     .columns(2).Replace What:="* - ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=2, _
        SearchOrder:=1, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has already been said you need to deal with the Excel VBA constants like xlToRight.

One way to do that is to substitute the constants for their values, another is to declare them as constants at the top of your code like this.

```
Const xlToRight = -4161
Const xlPart = 2
Const xlByRows = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem was a little bit diffrent *Replace* function in excel vba and access vba. Now i only use:

```
.columns(2).Replace What:=" - *", Replacement:=""
```

Problem solved.

**EDIT:** 
It sholud be

```
.columns(2).Replace What:="* - ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=2, _
        SearchOrder:=1, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
```